# Is there a name for letters that "cross the line" (hang low) when written in lowercase (g, j, p, q, y)?

Tags: single-word-requests, typography

Is there a fancy name for these letters that "hang low"?

Comment: I can remember that in the days of dot matrix printers, any printer that actually printed descenders below the line (as opposed to tucking them up into the 8 by 8 grid the cheaper ones had) was said to possess "hanging doobreys".

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes, they're called [descenders](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/descender), a term which also refers to the part of the letter that dips below the line.

Comment: To clarify: the descender is the part of the letter that goes below the line. I don't know if there's a one-word term for letters that have descenders.

Comment: @JSBangs: The term "descenders" refers to both - look at the dictionary entry that I linked to in my answer.

Comment: The NOAD defines _descender_ in the same way.

Comment: And the other type are "ascenders," e.g., b,d,f, etc.

Answer (score 9):

They *have* descenders. I don't think the letters themselves have a name.

Edit: I stand corrected.

> a. The part of the lowercase letters, such as g, p, and q, that extends below the other lowercase letters.
>   b. **A letter with such a part.**

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/descender

Comment: In the link that psmears posted, it said that it refers to both the part that goes below and the letter itself.

Answer (score 3):

Letters like *g, p, q* and *j* are called *descenders* or *descending letters.*

Comment: Good answer, especially for noting that these are sometimes also called descending letters. This would be even better if you included a reference or other evidence.